# Magento 2. Access Place Order Request Payload On The Server Side (PHP)

Tags: magento2, place-order

When placing and order via storefront a request is made towards `/rest/default/V1/carts/mime/payment-information`.

Inspecting the request in the browser I can see a Request Payload. (see atached).

How do I access this on the server side?
It's not on the **request** object, I can't find it in any of the **Super Globals**, in fact I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I found a way using plain php `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);`. Still doesn't Magento need/use/store this information somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Request Payload` information is translated into the parameter types of `\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()` and passed to this method.

[image]